# Magento 2 shopping cart based on quanity

Tags: cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.3.6

i want to cart rule setup for specific category product 
my all product price is $14.99 
so i want to rule like
when customer buy 1 product price total : $14.99 
when customer buy 2 products total  : $20 
when customer buy 3 products total : $34.99 
when customer buy 4 products total : $40

i have setup it but it not working when quantity is 3

[image]

[image]

Comment: In your condition you are mension the qty like 2,4,6 etc then how it work for 3?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya yes right i want to when 3 quantity come it it working rule like for 2 quantity and other price is same like so total price is $34.99

Comment: then you need to create separate rule according to that one.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya how ? can you help us for that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Magento Default not introduced this kind of feature yet.

**You can use [Amasty Special Promotions for Magento 2](https://amasty.com/special-promotions-for-magento-2.html)**

See cart price rule "Buy pushup grips and a sprite foam roller for just $25" in admin of amasty demo

Comment: thanks for an answer but i have checked that is not possible in that rule